# Problem with generating multiple html files form one xml documrnt

Tags: xml, xslt

Im trying to divide one xml document into more html files by "auto" (car) element. I also want to have one main html document where is gonna be list with links to those files. But it only generates the main file with links and doesnt generate anything else.

I dont know why it doesnt work. It seems like everything is alright to me.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:au="http://example.com/autobazar" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs au" version="2.0">

    <xsl:output method="html" encoding="UTF-8"/>
    <xsl:output method="html" encoding="UTF-8" name="html"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">
            &lt;!DOCTYPE html&gt;
        </xsl:text>
        <html lang="cs">
            <head>
                <title>Autobazar</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <xsl:apply-templates mode="hlavniSeznam"/>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="au:autobazar" mode="hlavniSeznam">
        <h1>Autobazar</h1>
        <ul>
            <xsl:for-each select="au:auto">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="hlavniSeznam"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </ul>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="au:auto" mode="hlavniSeznam">
        <li>
            <a href="auto{generate-id()}.html">
                <xsl:value-of select="au:znacka"/> - <xsl:value-of select="au:model"/>
            </a>
        </li>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="au:auto" mode="popisky">
        <xsl:for-each select="//au:autobazar/au:auto">
            <xsl:result-document href="auto{generate-id()}.html">
                <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">
                  &lt;!DOCTYPE html&gt;
                 </xsl:text>
                <html>
                    <head>
                        <title>
                            <xsl:value-of select="au:znacka"/>
                            <xsl:value-of select="au:model"/>
                        </title>
                    </head>
                    <body>
                        <h1>
                            <xsl:value-of select="au:znacka"/>
                            <xsl:value-of select="au:model"/>
                        </h1>
                    </body>
                </html>
            </xsl:result-document>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<autobazar xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://example.com/autobazar autobazar.xsd"
    xmlns="http://example.com/autobazar">

    <auto vin="JTJHF10U310224808">
        <znacka>Škoda</znacka>
        <model>Octavia RS</model>
        <generace>Mk3</generace>
        <motor>
            <objem jednotka="ccm">1998</objem>
            <palivo>benzin</palivo>
            <vykon jednotka="kw">160</vykon>
            <valce>4</valce>
            <tocivyMoment jednotka="nm">320</tocivyMoment>
            <spotreba jednotka="l/100km">12</spotreba>
            <prevodovka>automatická</prevodovka>
        </motor>
        <pohon>přední</pohon>
        <zrychleni jednotka="s">8.6</zrychleni>
        <maximalniRychlost jednotka="km/h">246</maximalniRychlost>
        <karoserie>combi</karoserie>
        <zavazadlovyProstor jednotka="l">560</zavazadlovyProstor>
        <pohotovostniHmostnost jednotka="kg">1454</pohotovostniHmostnost>
        <lak>
            <barva>modrá</barva>
            <typLaku>metalíza</typLaku>
        </lak>
        <cena jednotka="kč">450000</cena>
        <najeto jednotka="km">87000</najeto>
        <rokVyroby>2015</rokVyroby>
        <registraceInzeratu>2018-01-26</registraceInzeratu>
        <fotka src="skodars3.jpg"/>
    </auto>

    <auto vin="5XYKUDA19BG186713">
        <znacka>Hyundai</znacka>
        <model>i30N</model>
        <generace>Mk3</generace>
        <motor>
            <objem jednotka="ccm">1998</objem>
            <palivo>benzin</palivo>
            <vykon jednotka="kw">202</vykon>
            <valce>4</valce>
            <tocivyMoment jednotka="nm">353</tocivyMoment>
            <spotreba jednotka="l/100km">9.1</spotreba>
            <prevodovka>manuální</prevodovka>
        </motor>
        <pohon>přední</pohon>
        <zrychleni jednotka="s">6.1</zrychleni>
        <maximalniRychlost jednotka="km/h">250</maximalniRychlost>
        <karoserie>hatchback</karoserie>
        <zavazadlovyProstor jednotka="l">436</zavazadlovyProstor>
        <pohotovostniHmostnost jednotka="kg">1584</pohotovostniHmostnost>
        <lak>
            <barva>modrá</barva>
            <typLaku>metalíza</typLaku>
        </lak>
        <cena jednotka="kč">679000</cena>
        <najeto jednotka="km">5000</najeto>
        <rokVyroby>2018</rokVyroby>
        <registraceInzeratu>2019-01-21</registraceInzeratu>
        <fotka src="i30n.jpg"/>
    </auto>


</autobazar>
```

It should generate files for each "auto" and one main file with list of links. It only generates the main file and not anything else.

Thank you and sorry for bad english

Comment: You have a template for a mode `mode="popisky"` but you do not use it anywhere so somewhere you want/need to use `<xsl:apply-templates mode="popisky"/>`, perhaps with an appropriate `select` attribute.

Comment: Please delete your previous question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56367555/problem-with-generating-multiple-html-files-from-one-xml-document

Comment: Yes, that was it! Thank you! I added <xsl:apply-templates mode="popisky"/> to main body and it is working now.